# addchild movieclip appear in wrong scene

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

i used addchild in movieclip at scene 2, but when i went to scene 1 with button, the object which used addchild keep appeared. and than when i back to scene 2 again, the object which used addchild move faster then before.any idea?

this is my code:

```
var Batumc:batu_mc = new batu_mc();
var Batumc1:batu_mc = new batu_mc();

var BatasBatu = Batumc.width/12;

        addChild(Batumc);
        Batumc.x = 100;
        Batumc.y = 50;

        addChild(Batumc1);
        Batumc1.x = 100;
        Batumc1.y = 50;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Scene**s are not separate entities, they exist only for you to keep your designs logically ordered. When compiled, all scenes are converted into a single main timeline **MovieClip**.

Then, when your script adds anything to a timeline, Flash Player won't remove these things just because you **gotoAndPlay** to another frame.

That's exactly why mixing multi-frame timeline designs with scripting is not a good idea: Flash Player doesn't automatically control things you program, like it does to pre-designed timeline entities.

So, the possible solutions.

1. Take full control of the things you do. Before going to another 'scene', unsubscribe all the events you subscribed to (that is important, because subscriptions can bind objects and funtions and prevent their auto-ending) and remove all the things you've manually added there. With **removeChildren()** method, for example.
2. Wrap each 'scene' of yours into a container **MovieClip**. Whatever you do inside container, it will disappear once you **gotoAndPlay** to another frame, where that container just does not physically exist. The need to unsubscribe things is still in effect though.

Comment: i've followed your suggestion, but when i go back to scene 2 again the addchild still move fast than before and sometimes it doesn't eppear. can you help me?   @Organis

Comment: @Tamara If you add the relevant scripts to your question. You haven't explained how do you move them, which could (or could not) be the cornerstone of the problem.

Comment: so, can you tell me how to unsubcribe and which event i need to fix? @Organis

Comment: @Tamara Upon moving to another 'scene' you should call **removeEventListener** for each and every **addEventListener** you did.

Comment: can you give an example? i've tried to put it in the bottom of script and inside function self but still doesn't work.    ````tombolplay.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
function start(e:MouseEvent) {
 gotoAndStop("play","play");
 
 tombolplay.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, start);
}````   @Organis

Comment: As I answered you on another question, google > **as3 removeeventlistener example**, there are dozens of illustrious and well-explained examples.